# Find the pdf of Z given X and Y

Tags: probability

Let $X$ have density

$$f_X(x) = 6x(1 − x) \quad[0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1]$$

Let $Y$ have density

$$f_Y(y) = 3y\quad[0\leqslant y\leqslant 1]$$

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Z = X^2Y$, find the density of $Z$

The approach I took was to find the cdf of $Z$ so that $F_Z(z) = P(X^2Y \leqslant z)$ and that $f(x,y) = 6x(1-x)2y$, but I am unsure about how to set up the integrals for calculating $F_Z$

Answer (score 1):

You have $\mathsf P(Z\leqslant z)=\mathsf P(X^2Y\leqslant z)$ so apply the Law of Total Probability -- and make use of the fact of independence.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Z\leqslant z)&=\mathsf P(X^2Y\leqslant z)\\[1ex]&=\int_\Bbb R \mathsf P(X^2\leqslant z/y\mid Y=y)~f_Y(y)~\mathsf d y\\[1ex]&=\int_\Bbb R \mathsf P(X^2\leqslant z/y)~f_Y(y)~\mathsf d y\\[2ex]F_Z(z)&=\int_{\Bbb R}\int_0^{\surd(z/y)} f_X(x)~f_Y(y)~\mathsf d x~\mathsf d y\\[2ex] f_Z(z) &=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\mathsf d~~}{\mathsf d z}F_Z(z)\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]&=\int_\Bbb R \left\lvert\tfrac{1}{2\surd (yz)}\right\rvert~f_X(\surd(z/y))~f_Y(y)~\mathsf d y\\&\ddots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\renewcommand{\dd}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}#1}$For any given $z$, the region is bounded by the contour curve $x^2y = z \implies y = z / x^2$ which to the human eye looks like $y = 1/x$. The contour curves intersect with the unit square on "top" at $y = 1$ (and $x = \sqrt{z}$) and on the right at $x = 1$. That is, the region can be split into two parts: on the left a column of width $\sqrt{z}$ and full height of $1$, on the right the area under $y = z / x^2$.

\begin{align}
P(X^2 Y \leqslant z) &= \int_0^{\sqrt{z}} f_X(x) \dd{x} + \int_{x = \sqrt{z}}^1 \int_{y = 0}^{z/x^2} f_X(x) f_Y(x) \dd{y}  \dd{x} 
\end{align}

Can you take it from here?$\endgroup$